# How dose print() function impact sub process's life cycle in python?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

If I use print() function in subprocess, then subprocess will terminate as soone as the main process terminated.
The following programs terminate at the same time.

```py
# main.py
import time
from subprocess import Popen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc = Popen(['python', 'sub.py'])
```

```py
# sub.py
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)
```

However if I comment the print() in sub.py, then sub process continues after main terminates.
Also, If I redirect it's stdout in main.py (see following) , the sub process continues as well.

```py
# main.py
import time
from subprocess import Popen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('a.txt", 'w') as out:
        proc = Popen(['python', 'sub.py'],stdout=out)
```

Comment: supplement: I use windows

Comment: What you state is just wrong. sub.py will run as another process even if main.py terminates. You may not see its output but it will run. You can also try to pipe its output in a file like ```proc = Popen("python3 sub.py > test.txt", shell=True)```and you will see the printed output in that file afterwards.

Besides of that, you are missing the time import in sub.py.